# "Application for Android" versus "application on Android"

Tags: vocabulary, pronouns

Which one is correct/most scientific?

- I am developing a certain application **for** Android.
- I am developing a certain application **on** Android.
- I am developing a certain application **for** the platform Android.
- I am developing a certain application **on** the platform Android.

Comment: "platform Android" wouldn't it rather be "Android platform"?

Comment: MrHen already pointed this out to me, but thanks anyway. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both are correct but have different meanings. Developing something *for* Android would mean that the application would eventually run *on* Android. Developing *on* Android would mean that you run development tools with Android in order to make your software.

Typically, part of the process for developing something *for* a platform involves using the platform itself, so *for* sort of implies the *on*. But using *on* wouldn't properly reference where you actually do most of your development: On a platform other than Android (such as Windows.)

The short answer is that the best choice is:

> I am developing a certain application for Android

---

As for your other suggestions, they work best when the people you are talking to don't know what Android is. It is usually worded as such, however:

> I am developing a certain application for the Android platform

In computing, *platform* typically comes after the relevant name:

> Macintosh platform
>
> Windows platform
>
> iOS platform

Comment: The application is meant to run ON Android :)

Comment: Just now I'm developing an application for Android, on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add something after Android:

I am developing a certain application for Android phones.
I am developing a certain application for Android devices.

I agree with MrHen that "I am developing a certain application for Android" is the best choice of your original options.  It's definitely correct.  But I think that in practice, people aren't using Android by itself yet like they would for, say, mac or Windows.

Speaking as someone who actually does develop Android applications (for learning English, even: market.android.com/details?id=com.realpeopletalk), things I say are:

I'm developing an Android app.
I'm working on an Android app.
I've got an Android app that I'm working on.
I write software for Android phones (usually said to non-technical people).

Answer (score 0):

"I am developing a certain application for the Android platform."

Sounds a bit more preferable.

Comment: Some sort of reason would be helpful, even if it's just "This is more used in (where I come from)". Also, *more preferable* is only slightly preferable to *more better*.